# How to get data fully replicated on all nodes in simple apache ignite cluster?

Tags: ignite

I'm trying to set up a simple 2 node cluster where ALL the data is fully synced and persisted to disk on ALL nodes but I can't figure out the configuration to achieve this.

Version: apache ignite 2.8.0.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve: 
My app instance can connect to any of the nodes in the cluster and do CRUD operations. If one of the nodes in the ignite cluster dies, the app should be able to connect to the other node and ALL data should be available there.
This is a small data set with minimal traffic so I'm not worried about performance as much as consistency.

Here's my configuration:

```
    .....
    .....
    <bean id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration"><property name="cacheConfiguration">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">              
            <property name="name" value="myCache"/>
            <property name="cacheMode" value="REPLICATED"/>
            <property name="backups" value="1"/>
            <property name="rebalanceMode" value="SYNC"/>
            <property name="writeSynchronizationMode" value="FULL_SYNC"/>
            <property name="partitionLossPolicy" value="READ_ONLY_SAFE"/>
        </bean>
    </property>

    <!-- Enabling Apache Ignite Persistent Store. -->
    <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
            <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                    <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="walMode" value="FSYNC"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    .....
    <!-- left out the discoverySpi config for brevity, it's just a multicast ip finder setup -->
    .....
```

What I've observed:

I clear all the data (/work directory) on each node to start fresh. I start both nodes for the first time, I activate the cluster (baseline topology is 2), I connect using a JDBC Client (e.g. DBeaver) with jdbc thin driver and I create a table, insert some data.

I can see all the data is there, which ever node I connect to.

I now kill one of the nodes. Connecting to the live node I see only some of the data. 
With my configuration I would expect all the data to be backed up and available. OR, due to the partitionLossPolicy I would expect to get an exception if the data was not synced yet and I'm trying to read it.

It seems this should be possible, what am I missing here?

Comment: This may be related to baseline topology, have you tried adjusting baseline topology as soon as node joins or leaves?

Comment: What do you mean by "I activate the cluster, _I create table_,"? You create a replicated cache in the XML and that should survive a node failing. Are you saying you create another cache (using SQL maybe?) and _that_ is the one you're seeing data loss in?

Comment: @Alamar - From what I understand, the BLT determines which nodes will actually persist data to disk and thus, the 2 nodes should be in the BLT. If one dies, I would expect all the data (of the node which died) to have been replicated to the other node.

Comment: @StephenDarlington - I should have been more clear about this. So:
1 - After starting up both nodes for the first time you have to manually "activate" the cluster (this also sets the BLT if I understand correctly and is a 1 time manual task).
2 - I connect with a jdbc client (jdbc thin driver) and create a table using sql. I also insert some records. I can then connect to either node using jdbc, query the table and I see all the records.
3 - If I now kill any node, and I connect again to the "live" node, I will only see some of the records. Hence, not all the data was replicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignite has multiple different ways of creating caches. The problem here is that you (inadvertently) use two of them.

First, you create a cache called `myCache`. This is a replicated cache and would be able to survive a server node failing.

Then you create a cache using SQL. This is not the same as the above cache, even if you called it `myCache`. The default is a partitioned cache, which is why you see data loss.

To create a replicated cache using SQL, you need to use the WITH clause:

```sql
CREATE TABLE ignite (id LONG PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR) WITH “template=replicated”;
```

(You can also put `backups=1` instead, which will give you a partitioned cache that can survive one server node failing.)

Comment: This is exactly what I need and it works perfectly with your suggestion. Thank you so much, you saved me a lot of time!
For others who run into this, if you read the [documentation](https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/create-table) on CREATE TABLE carefully it is explained